# How do I change permissions on a ssh forwarded unix domain socket

Tags: ssh, unix, socket

consider the ssh command:

```
sudo ssh -L /my/local/sock:/var/remote_socket me@remote
```

This runs as root, so the created local unix domain socket has ownership root and 0600 permissions.

How do I tell ssh to create the socket with wider permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`StreamLocalBindMask`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#StreamLocalBindMask_4) option:

> ```
>  StreamLocalBindMask
>     Sets the octal file creation mode mask (umask) used when creating
> a Unix-domain socket file for local or remote port forwarding.
> This option is only used for port forwarding to a Unix-domain socket file.  
>     The default value is 0177, which creates a Unix-domain socket
> file that is readable and writable only by the owner. Note that
> not all operating systems honor the file mode on Unix-domain
> socket files.
> ```

For a socket open to any user:

```
sudo ssh -o StreamLocalBindMask=0111 -L /my/local/sock:/var/remote_socket me@remote
```

(or just `=0` ).

Comment: It seems with newer versions of ssh, this option does not work on the client-side. The same option can be set in the server's `sshd_config`, and this worked for me.
I used `StreamLocalBindMask 0117` for 0660 permissions.

Comment: the client-side controls the socket on the client-side, the server-side controls the socket on the server-side.